# How do I stop scrolling with javascript with a .click() button?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll

I am trying to have my gallery scroll horizontally but stop when the button is released. Another option I was thinking is to make the gallery smaller so that only one photo fits in the container at a time and then just adding a button to go to the next one. For now, how do I get this to work? The site is located [here.](http://2013.igem.org/Team%3aGeorgia_State/Team/members)

```
    //Scrolling 
var amount = '';

function scroll() {
    $('#photosContainer').animate({
        scrollLeft: amount
    }, 100, 'linear',function() {
        if (amount != '') {
            scroll();
        }
    });
}
$('#scrollDown').mousedown(function() {
    amount = '+=10';
    scroll();
});
$('#scrollDown').mouseup(function(){
    $(this).stop(true);
});
$('#scrollUp').mousedown(function() {
    amount = '-=10';
    scroll();
});
$('#scrollUp').mouseup(function(){
    $(this).stop(true);
});
```

Comment: you're using the `.stop()` method on the button instead on the `#photosContainer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that on the `mouseup` function, you are trying to stop the button from moving. But the button isn't moving at all, so the script basically ignores this code. If you change the function from `this` to `#photosContainer`, it will stop on `mouseup`

```
$('#scrollUp').mouseup(function(){
  $('#photosContainer').stop(true);
});

$('#scrollDown').mouseup(function(){
  $('#photosContainer').stop(true);
});
```

You also don't really need the `true` in there, because there is nothing in your code that would contradict the `stop()` being set to `true`

I would also recommend changing the functions to `on()`, becaue `mouseup` and `mousedown` are depreciated

Comment: Thanks! I figured I just wasn't seeing something simple like that.